# test data in yml file and many-to-many relationship

Tags: playframework

I have software<-m:n->tag where software is **main part** of the relationship (tag has `mappedby="softwares"`).

So, then, when I want to import test data to database I put:

```
 Software(software1):
   title: title1
   description: descr1

 Software(software2):
   title: title2
   description: descr2

 Tag(tag1):
   title: pay
   softwares: [software1]

 Tag(tag2):
   title: pay2
   softwares: [software2]
```

After this script performed we got all data filled, and new table Tag_Software will be created with relationship data inside.

But, for me it would be more logical to change the order of Tag and Software here:

```
 Tag(tag1):
   title: pay

 Tag(tag2):
   title: pay2

 Software(software1):
   title: title1
   description: descr1
   tags: [tag1]

 Software(software2):
   title: title2
   description: descr2
   tags: [tag2]
```

I.e. I can create Tag separately, and then when creating a Software just put this Tag to this Software - making link. (It should work, because it works in Java Code). But it doesn't work here - as a result we have empty Tag_Software table.

Could you explain this behavior ? Or how to do it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you yourself answer the question. You say that:

> have software<-m:n->tag where
>   software is main part of the
>   relationship (tag has
>   mappedby="softwares").

this means that the attribute "softwares" manages the rel and you need to add the links there. If you add them to the other end the rel won't be established (as you saw).

If you want to change this, modify the **mappedBy** to tags